# Is kmalloc allocation not virtually contiguous?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I found that `kmalloc` returns physically and virtually contiguous memory.

I wrote some code to observe the behavior, but only the physical memory seems to be contiguous and not the virtual. Am I making any mistake?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static char *ptr;
int alloc_size = 1024;

module_param(alloc_size, int, 0);

static int test_hello_init(void)
{
    ptr = kmalloc(alloc_size,GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(!ptr) {
        /* handle error */
        pr_err("memory allocation failed\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    } else {
        pr_info("Memory allocated successfully:%p\t%p\n", ptr, ptr+100);
        pr_info("Physical address:%llx\t %llx\n", virt_to_phys(ptr), virt_to_phys(ptr+100));
    }

    return 0;
}

static void test_hello_exit(void)
{
    kfree(ptr);
    pr_info("Memory freed\n");

}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

`dmesg` output:

```
Memory allocated successfully:0000000083318b28  000000001fba1614
Physical address:1d5d09c00   1d5d09c64
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this is your problem, but during my exploration of the linux kernel I figured out that the format specifier %p with the printk method returns wrong addresses. Are you sure that your pr_info with the %p specifier returns valid pointer addresses? My work-around was to cast the address to an unsigned long long and use %llx. Maybe give that a try?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Printing kernel pointers is in general a bad idea, because it basically means leaking kernel addresses to user space, so when using `%p` in `printk()` (or similar macros like `pr_info()` etc.), the kernel tries to protect itself and does not print the real address. Instead, it prints a different hashed unique identifier for that address.

If you *really* want to print that address, you can use `%px`.

---

From `Documentation/core-api/printk-formats.rst` ([web version](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/core-api/printk-formats.html), [git](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/core-api/printk-formats.rst?h=v5.18&id=4b0986a3613c92f4ec1bdc7f60ec66fea135991f)):

> ### Pointer Types
>
> Pointers printed without a specifier extension (i.e unadorned `%p`) **are
> hashed to give a unique identifier without leaking kernel addresses to user
> space**. On 64 bit machines the first 32 bits are zeroed. If you *really*
> want the address see `%px` below.
>
> ```
> %p    abcdef12 or 00000000abcdef12
> ```

Then, later below:

> ### Unmodified Addresses
>
> ```
> %px   01234567 or 0123456789abcdef
> ```
>
> For printing pointers when you *really* want to print the address. Please
> consider whether or not you are leaking sensitive information about the
> Kernel layout in memory before printing pointers with `%px`. `%px` is
> functionally equivalent to `%lx`. `%px` is preferred to `%lx` because it is more
> uniquely grep'able. If, in the future, we need to modify the way the Kernel
> handles printing pointers it will be nice to be able to find the call
> sites.

---

For what it's worth, the code that converts plain pointers (formatted with `%p`) before printing can be found [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L806). The call chain in Linux 6.6 is: [`_printk()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2326) → [`vprintk()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk_safe.c#L29) → [`vprintk_default()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2320) → [`vprintk_emit()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2266) → [`vprintk_store()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2266) → [`printk_sprint()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2122) → [`vscnprintf()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2917) → [`vsnprintf()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2748) → [`pointer()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2407) → [`default_pointer()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L836) → [`ptr_to_id()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L806).

Comment: In the Linux Source code it is present in Documentation/core-api/printk-formats.rst file

Comment: Marco, on the web it has much better view: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html

Comment: @0andriy yeah, indeed that's better, thanks.

Comment: Can you link the source code that hashes kernel addresses?

Comment: @vmemmap a bit late, but done :')