# why printk prints different values while using __va

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I encountered with a Linux module that maps register and use `__va()` for that. I added three printk at the end of the mapping to check what does `__va()` macro do except of the casting to `void *`. I also tried to cast it by my self and mimic the `__va()`

```c
printk(KERN_DEBUG "reg_val - 0x%llx\n", regVal);
printk(KERN_DEBUG "reg_val manual casting %p \n", (((void *)((unsigned long)(regVal)))));
printk(KERN_DEBUG "reg_val __va %p \n", __va(regval));
```

This is what I got

```
[  435.136161] reg_val - 0x26dd1a000
[  435.136162] reg_val manual casting 000000005249cc54
[  435.136164] reg_val __va 00000000c000348a
```

My question is why each line give me different output? Specially the last two lines that should do same.

Comment: `%p` does not print a kernel address, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is kmalloc allocation not virtually contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757876/is-kmalloc-allocation-not-virtually-contiguous)