# raw_spin_lock(): unexpected null pointer exception

Tags: linux-kernel

So I adapted some of the /kernel/sched/rt.c code to write my own simple CPU scheduler, and I'm getting a null pointer dereference exception when I try to acquire a lock. This is despite me printk()'ing all of the relevant pointers, and seeing that they're not NULL.

```
    //Snippet from my adaptation of update_curr_rt()
    //wrr_rq is a struct wrr_rq*

    printk("Before loop, wrr_rq pointer is %p\n",wrr_rq);
    printk("Before loop, &wrr_rq->wrr_runtime_lock is %p\n",&wrr_rq->wrr_runtime_lock);

    for_each_sched_wrr_entity(wrr_se) {
        printk("1\n");
        wrr_rq = wrr_rq_of_se(wrr_se); 
        printk("2\n");
        raw_spin_lock(&wrr_rq->wrr_runtime_lock);
        printk("3\n");
```

```
[  263.595176] Before loop, wrr_rq is 00000000aebb4d6d
[  263.596283] Before loop, &wrr_rq->wrr_runtime_lock is 0000000015dee87f
[  263.597764] 1
[  263.598141] wrr_rq_of_se: called
[  263.598888] 2
[  263.599268] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000068
[  263.600836] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
[  263.602027] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page

...

[  263.656134] RIP: 0010:_raw_spin_lock+0x7/0x20
```

I've printed all the relevant pointers and seen they're not NULL (and have values quite a bit above 0), but I still get this exception. I tried using the elixir browser to see what is happening with the raw_spin_lock() macro, and it doesn't seem like anything crazy is happening...

In addition, the runqueue lock is already held when this code is called (the runqueue lock is acquired by  task_sched_runtime()).

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is kmalloc allocation not virtually contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757876/is-kmalloc-allocation-not-virtually-contiguous)

Comment: How is the `wrr_rq` pointer printed before the loop related to the `wrr_rq` pointer inside the loop? Maybe you should print that value where you have `printk("2\n");`, i.e. `printk("2, wrr_rq is %p\n", wrr_rq);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott that's a great suggestion. Unfortunately, when I went ahead and added your suggested print statement, I still print a valid pointer value, and the lock still errors out with a null pointer exception.

Comment: @0andriy your suggestion to print the pointers %px instead of %p confirmed that what initially appeared to be valid pointers, were in fact NULL pointers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @0andriy: It turns out that kernel NULL pointers when printed by %p get hashed to some other unique value that may not be NULL, and so when I printed things with %px I saw they were in fact NULL.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that they didn't treat NULL as a special case!

Comment: Agreed... it's funny, this is probably the first time in my life where a seriously frustrating bug actually turned out to be some implementation quirk, rather than my own mistake.