# Storing address of char* in a variable

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel, char, linux-device-driver

I have char* s = "some msg", and I want to split and store the address in two values.

What I want:

```
char* s = "some msg"
printf("%p", s) // 00034a00050de0b5
// u32 firstHalf = 00034a00;
// u32 secondHalf = 050de0b5;
```

I read about uinptr_t being used for storing addresses so I tried:

```
uintptr_t p = s;
print("%p", p) // 00034a00050de0b5
printf("0x%lx", p) // print some other value 0xffff8f12c7727c00, I thought this would be 0x00034a00050de0b5
u32 firstHalf = p>>32; // 0xffff8f12, but want 00034a00
u32 secondHalf = p; // 0xc7727c00, but want 050de0b5
```

I obviously have conceptual misunderstandings, so please clarify.

code to reproduce

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
pr_info("module inserted\n");
  char *s = "some msg";
  pr_info("s %p\n", s);
  uintptr_t v = s;
  pr_info("v %p\n", (void*)v);
  pr_info("v 0x%llx\n", v); // prints something different from above
  uint32_t h1 = v>>32;
  uint32_t h2 = v;
  pr_info("h1 0x%x\n", h1);
  pr_info("h2 0x%x\n", h2);
  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    pr_info("module removed\n");
}

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("kernel module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("anonymous@gmail.com");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: `printf("0x%lx", p)` won't work if type `long` is 32 bits and type `uintptr_t` is 64 bits.  Try `printf("0x%llx", p)`.

Comment: `printf("%p", p)` might work but is not strictly correct.  `%p` is for printing pointers (specifically void pointers), not ints.  It's better to write `printf("%p", (void *)p)`.

Comment: I don't know why your "first" and "second" halves seemed to be reversed.  When I try the code on my computer, I get `34a00` and `50de0b5`, as expected.

Comment: It's possible that the code you've shown is not the code you're running, and therefore that the problem exists in the code you're running, but is invisible to us because we can see only the code you've posted.  Please try to present a complete, minimal, compilable and runnable example (with `main()` and `#include` lines and everything).  Please present it by copying and posting your exact code if you can, not by retyping it.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/kWkTLDxp93. This is working as expected. But am running this code inside kernel driver (`pr_info` instead of `printf` ofc), there `pr_info("v 0x%llx\n", v);` is printing different value than expected.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are running.

Comment: @ruke, you should provide a [mre] of a simple module that reproduces the problem you are facing along with the actual vs expected output. Note that we need the code for a module, not just some userspace C program with a few lines of code inside a `main`.

Comment: How did you print out `firstHalf` and `secondHalf`, that told you they were `0xffff8f12` and `0xc7727c00`?  Sometimes the kernel printf routines are even fussier about using exactly the right format specifiers.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli added the code.

Comment: @ruke ok that's good. The module you show does not compile though, I had to change a couple of things to make it compile.

Comment: Anyway, this is the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757876/is-kmalloc-allocation-not-virtually-contiguous/57758230#57758230 `%p` in kernel space does NOT print the real address of a variable, it hashes it. `%px` prints the real address. In other words, with `%p` you are seeing a fake address, and with `%llx` or `%lx` you are seeing the correct values.