# How does address of kernel directly mapping area map to physical address

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

In my first thought, I think when convert kernel virtual address in directly mapping zone to physical address. It should just minus the page_offset_base(0xffff888000000000 in 4-level paging).

But I do a simple test, I write a kernel module and require some memory by `kmalloc()`, then print it out in %x format and %p format. There are different in lower bits, not a minus of page_offset_base. I'm wondering why?

here is my code:

```
buf_high = (char*)kmalloc(140, __GFP_HIGHMEM);
buf = (char*)kmalloc(140, GFP_KERNEL);

printk("kmalloc highmem : %lx, %p\n", buf_high, buf_high);
printk("kmalloc : %lx, %p\n", buf, buf);
```

Here is the output:

```
[ 1157.671135] kmalloc highmem : ffff888118d2b000, 000000009412a3d4
[ 1157.671142] kmalloc : ffff888118d2b3c0, 000000009ce9058c
```

Comment: The direct mapping area you are thinking of is the kernel text, not the heap data.

Comment: @stark I think OP is talking about `ffff888000000000` i.e. "direct mapping of all physical memory (page_offset_base)", the kernel text is mapped at `ffffffff80000000` ([doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt)).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes that's what I'm thinking. I use directly mapping area instead of direct mapping of all physical memory (page_offset_base) just to avoid a looooooooong title.

Comment: Anyway, printing the same thing with `%lx` or `%p` should not change the value, it's always the same, so I don't know what is the purpose of the code you show. There is a little gotcha here because `printk` with `%p` will hash the address for security, and you should use `%px` instead if you want the real value ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758230/3889449)).